# unCSS ignore list globbing

Tags: css, wordpress, gulp, glob, gulp-uncss

### Context

I'm using gulp-uncss to remove unused CSS in a wordpress theme. It works fine, but unCSS can't recover styles from user account page because it is behind a login. All styles into account page are removed by unCSS.

So, I am editing a ignore list.

### Problem

The ignore list is very large and I have used a lot of time to write and test it.

### Question

Is there some way to write something like glob pattern into the list?

### Example

My current ignore list looks like:

```
ignore: [
        '.woocommerce-checkout.woocommerce-order-received h2',
        '.woocommerce-checkout.woocommerce-order-received .shop_table th.product-name',
        '.woocommerce-checkout.woocommerce-order-received .shop_table th.product-total',
        '.woocommerce-checkout.woocommerce-order-received .woocommerce-thankyou-order-received',
        '.woocommerce-checkout.woocommerce-order-received .woocommerce-thankyou-order-details',
        '.woocommerce-checkout.woocommerce-order-received .woocommerce-thankyou-order-details li',
        '.woocommerce-checkout.woocommerce-order-received .woocommerce-thankyou-order-details',
         etc
         ...
```

I want something like:

```
ignore: [
        '.woocommerce-checkout*'
```

Is it possible? Thank you in advance.